# Can't pass class object array into function?

Tags: c++, function, class, parameter-passing

I am trying to use a function to calculate a grade average and store the letter grade into "letter". However, whenever I try to call the function, I get an error saying "no matching for call to "findAvg". I do not completely understand references and pointers. Is that the issue here? Any help and information is appreciated, thank you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class Student{
 public:
  double grades[4];
  float avgGrade;
  string letter;
  string name;
};

void findAvg(Student f[]);

int main(){
  Student students[3];
  int i = 0;
  fstream fin;
  fin.open("input1.txt");
  while(!fin.eof()){
    fin >> students[i].name;
    for (int j =0; j < 4;++j){
      fin >> students[i].grades[j];
    }
    i += 1;
  }
  fin. close();
  findAvg(students[3]);
  cout << students[1].letter;
}

void findAvg(Student f[]){
  for(int i = 0;i<3;++i){
    f[i].avgGrade = ((f[i].grades[0] + f[i].grades[1] + f[i].grades[2] + f[i].grades[3]) /4);
    if (f[i].avgGrade>=90){
      f[i].letter = "A";
    } else if (89>f[i].avgGrade && f[i].avgGrade<=80){
      f[i].letter = "B";
    } else if (79>f[i].avgGrade && f[i].avgGrade<=70){
      f[i].letter = "C";
    } else if (69>f[i].avgGrade && f[i].avgGrade<=60){
      f[i].letter = "D";
    } else {
      f[i].letter = "F";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: frankly, the problem is that you do not understand c-arrays. Thats no shame, they are horrible. Use `std::vector` for dynamic arrays and `std::array` for fixed size. What do you think this line is doing `findAvg(students[3]);` ?

Comment: I thought I was calling the function to find the average of grades and assign each student a letter grade. Is that not whats happening?

Comment: @ZachSal You are not calling the function with the correct syntax. Specifically your understanding of arrays in expressions is wrong.

Comment: As an aside, if your student has an `avgGrade` of `89.5`, then your code will assign that as an __F__.

Comment: Don't edit your question to say "SOLVED". Instead accept one of the answers. If none of them is good enough, write your own answer and accept that.

Answer (score 2):

```
findAvg(students[3]);
```

should be

```
findAvg(students);
```

The idea that you reference the whole array, by using `array[SIZE]` (where SIZE is the size of the array) is a common newbie error. I guess it comes from a confusion between the *array declaration* and an *expression*. But declarations and expressions are not the same thing and different rules apply. In an expression `array[n]` always references an *element* of the array. And furthermore if `n` is the same as the size of the array then you are referencing an element that does not exist.

The strange thing is that you handle the arrays perfectly correctly in every other part of your code, `students[i].grades[j];` for instance. But for some reason when you are calling the `findAvg` function you think different rules apply.

Answer (score 1):

Try `findAvg (students)` instead of `findAvg (students[3])`.  `students[3]` would give you the 4th student, which does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Your call `findAvg(students[3]);` is incorrect. You've defined a function that takes an array, but `students[3]` is a single `Student` object, not an array. It is also an error because it is trying to access an element outside the boundaries of the array

Try calling it as

```cpp
findAvg(students);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you need to paas the object array
So
use this

```
findAvg(students);
```

instead of using

```
findAvg(students[3]);
```